# I'm getting a google sheets error "wrong number of arguments to SUMIF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got seven

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

=SUMIF(B41:B101,E41:E141,E36,F41:F141,F38,G41:G141,G38)

Tring to sum the values in B with a criteria for the ranges in E, F, and G. I'm a project manager, not a developer and I want this to be pretty so I don't want to use a pivot table. Can you help me get my statement right?

I want it to display the total of values that meet all three criteria instead of giving me an error message

Answer (score 0):

You need `SUMIFS()`. Try-

```
=SUMIFS(B41:B101,E41:E141,E36,F41:F141,F38,G41:G141,G38)
```